# aws batch: submit job using lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, roles, aws-batch

Context: AWS, S3, **Lambda**, **Batch**.

I have a lambda that is triggered when a file is uploaded in a S3 Bucket. I want that the lambda submit a Batch job.

(edit: Between S3 and Lambda everything works fine. The problem is between Lambda and Batch.)

**Q**: What is the **role** I have to give to the **lambda** in order to be able to submit the batch job?

My lambda gets an `AccessDeniedException` and fail to submit the job when:

```
const params = {
  jobDefinition: BATCH_JOB_DEFINITION,
  jobName: BATCH_JOB_NAME,
  jobQueue: BATCH_JOB_QUEUE,
};

Batch.submitJob(params).promise() .then .......
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems that this was the role I was looking for: `batch:SubmitJob`. Using this role, the lambda was able to submit the job.

```
iamRoleStatements:
  - Effect: Allow
    Action:
      - batch:SubmitJob
    Resource: "arn:aws:batch:*:*:*"
```

Comment: Hi Costin. How did you figure out how to do this? Specifically, how did you realize the action you needed was `SubmitJob`? And how did you know the resource had to be `arn:aws:batch:*:*:*`? I see the resource has the same pattern as some other examples I found online (e.g. https://n2ws.com/blog/aws-automation/lambda-function-s3-event-triggers). But what is the difference between `arn:aws:batch:*:*:*` and `batch:*`?

Comment: I do not remember where I've seen it, but I thing there was a lucky guess from the [AWS Batch - Actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html) page. The `arn:aws:batch:*:*:*` follows the ARN syntax. Once you understand how it is built you'll be able to target any AWS resource, with closed eyes :)

Comment: It might be good to [restrict the resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/ExamplePolicies_BATCH.html#iam-example-restrict-job-def) available (e.g. don't want your testing lambda to deploy to a batch instance in production)

Answer (score 4):

You can Create a Policy like `AWS Batch Managed Policy`,

The following Policy Allows Admin Access,You can modify it as per your needs:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "batch:*",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
                "ecs:DescribeClusters",
                "ecs:Describe*",
                "ecs:List*",
                "logs:Describe*",
                "logs:Get*",
                "logs:TestMetricFilter",
                "logs:FilterLogEvents",
                "iam:ListInstanceProfiles",
                "iam:ListRoles"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["iam:PassRole"],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::*:role/AWSBatchServiceRole",
                "arn:aws:iam::*:role/ecsInstanceRole",
                "arn:aws:iam::*:role/iaws-ec2-spot-fleet-role",
                "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-ec2-spot-fleet-role",
                "arn:aws:iam::*:role/AWSBatchJobRole*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Attach the policy to lambda and try it again , Refer [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/batch_managed_policies.html)

Comment: Thanks Kush. There is no problem between S3 and Lambda. The problem is that Lambda can not launch the Batch (job).

Comment: Sorry Kush, but this is not the answer. These are the roles for the Batch. What I was looking for is the role for the **Lambda**. The role which enables `submitJob()` from within a lambda. Thanks.

Comment: But it can be achieved in that way also refer the aws documentaion